# How to use python to find value in excel cell next to another cell already found?

Tags: python, excel, wildcard

I would like to find the value of an excel cell in the cell NEXT to an already found cell.

My code:

```
file = openpyxl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx', read_only = True)
allSheetNames = file.sheetnames

print("All sheet names {}" .format(file.sheetnames))

for sheet in allSheetNames:
    print('Current sheet name is {}'.format(sheet))
    currentSheet = file[sheet]

    for row in range(1, currentSheet.max_row + 1):
        #print row
        for column in 'CDEF':  #Add or remove if needed
            cell_name = '{}{}'.format(column,row)
        
            if currentSheet[cell_name].value == 'BMS_RACK14.74': #<- working
                 print 'Cell position {} has value {}'.format(cell_name, currentSheet[cell_name].value)
```

The output is then:

```
All sheet names ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
Current sheet name is Sheet1
Current sheet name is Sheet2
Cell position E5 has value BMS_RACK14.74
Cell position D7 has value BMS_RACK14.74
Cell position E7 has value BMS_RACK14.74
```

I would like to get the value in the cell NEXT to E5, D7, and E7 (so in this case F5, E7, and F7). What to add in my code to get this value? I can not find a solution. Or is there an overall better way to solve this?

And also, I would like a tip on how my search for 'BMS_RACK14.74' could contain a wildcard, like BMS_RACK14?74 or BMS_RACK14*74.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

### Accessing neighbouring cell

If you use the `.cell()` [method](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell), you can avoid advancing a letter, and just add one to the column number, which you have access to from the `for` loop:

```py
for row in range(1, currentSheet.max_row + 1):
        #print row
        for column in 'CDEF':  #Add or remove if needed
            cell_name = '{}{}'.format(column,row)
        
            if currentSheet[cell_name].value == 'BMS_RACK14.74': #<- working
                 print('Cell position {} has value {}'.format(cell_name, currentSheet[cell_name].value))
                 print("Neighbouring cell's value: {}".format(currentSheet.cell(row=row, column=column+1))
```

### Tip for wildcards

A tip here would be Regex. W3Schools has [a great tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

I think editing your `if` to this would work:

```py
if re.search("^(BMS_RACK14.74)$", currentSheet[cell_name].value):
[...]
```

Comment: I get error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects" using .cell().  Any way of solving this and keeping the method? I will check out the wildcard tutorial now, thank you.

Comment: When trying Regex I get "TypeError: expected string or buffer", I have tried to make sure only one instans of my searach is in the excel file, but I keep getting same error.